# How to use a JSON object received by one JavaScript function in another function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I had written a function which returns JSON format via ajax call. The  JSON is

```
 {
    "communication": [{
        "communication_name": "None",
        "communication_id": "1"
    }],
    "hardware": [{
        "hardware_name": "XXXXXXXX",
        "hardware_id": "6"
    }],
    "Sofware": [{
        "software_name": "XXXXXX",
        "software_id": "3"
    }, {
        "software_name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "software_id": "4"
    }]
}
```

And this is the JavaScript  function for getting this response:

```
function getModelData(model_id, model_name){

     var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

    try {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajaxmodel_new.php?model_id="+model_id,true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
        var myJSONObject =  JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText)
        //alert(myJSONObject.communication[0].communication_name)
         }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    } catch (e){
    alert("Can't connect to server:\n" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

It is getting the correct response. And there is another function is for getting the selected value in the selected drop down:

```
<div id="selected_options">
                <select onchange="test()" id="selected_opt">
                <option value="0" selected>-Select-</option>
                <option value="1">Communication</option>
                             </select></div>
function test() {
    var get_id = document.getElementById('selected_opt');
    var result = get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(result);
}
```

### Objective

I need to use the JSON response, i.e., `myJSONObject`, in the `test()` function. How can I use that `var myJSONObject` which is obtained in `getModelData()` ajax function  in `test()` function?

Comment: Longest stackoverflow sentence EVER

Answer (score 4):

I had a different approach in parsing the **JSON Object**.

From the PHP side I create the object and store it in a variable say, `$JSONvar`. Now I `echo` the variable.

Then on the client side this is how I intercept the object.

```
var JsonObject = {};
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", url, true); //url is the url echoing the jsonString
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    var responseTxt = http.responseText;
    myJSONObject = eval('(' + responseTxt + ')');
    test(myJSONObject);
 }
}
http.send(null);
```

Your test function should be able to access the object like this,

```
function test(myJSONObject) {
var object = myJSONObject;
alert(object);
var get_id = document.getElementById('selected_opt');
var result = get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
alert(result);
}
```

Comment: i used here is we can declare myJSONObject as a global variable , so that we can access it anywhere inside the function

Comment: Using eval like this can be dangerous. If someone one your network is using a DNS man in the middle attack to redirect requests to another server, they could insert arbitrary JavaScript into the response and eval would run it.

Comment: I guess we can write a function to sanitize the return json value to check for injections and then eval it.

Answer (score 2):

Call `test()` from the function in `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange`, passing the decoded object as a parameter.

Comment: i'm not getting the correct thing can u plesae tell me in brief or how to code ?